# How to validate UIView has been displayed

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a tableview, and a tableviewcell from different part of the application. How do I know for sure that the cell has been displayed by the tableview?

I know that by checking
    if (view.window != nil) {
        // do stuff
    }

and 
    if (!view.hidden)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

in the tableviewcontroller, I can validate that the view did get displayed in the cell. But there are two issues:

- I am relying on the tableviewcontroller for the above checkes
- I will have to implement my own NSNotification or delegate to callback to the tableviewcell of the view being displayed.

Is there any other way to implement this, for example, something like viewdidappear from the UIVeiwController?

Comment: I use UIView's superview property.  It seemed to detect correctly so far: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Comment: How would you achieve it? By using: view.superview == nil ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the visible cells using `[_tableView visibleCells];` or

1. you could use an `NSIndexSet` where you add endries for each cell that has been loaded. Do this in the init method of the cell.
2. or you could set up a delegate in the cell and and tell your view controller when it has been initialized.

Comment: thanks @freshking. My issue is that I do not own the cell or the tableview. I guess I could use your second recommendation, but only to set the delegate in the view (I generate the view), and have the cell call the delegate method. The fundamental issue is still that I have to trust the cell or the tableview to call the delegate method at the appropriate time of execution.

Comment: I don't think that this is an issue. If you set up the delegate correctly it will definitely get called once the view is loaded.